# Running a new child process in background C linux

Tags: c, linux, process, background, fork

I am trying to run a new process in background so it will be possible to continue working with parent process.

I used fork then execl. I tried to add to the execl command the argument & but it doesn't work:

```
execl("newproc","newproc","arg1","&",NULL);
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `&` is not a command line option to programs.  Instead, it is merely special shell syntax which puts a command in the background.  The distinguishing feature of background programs is that they are not connected to a terminal, and the terminal is not waiting for the process to complete.  The proper function is `daemon()`.  Do a `man daemon` to read up on how it is used.

Comment: Sorry to be picky: `daemon(3)` is *not* a *system call*, it is a library function (implemented thru dual `fork` and `close` syscalls - listed in section 2 of `man` pages). Indeed, `daemon` is the appropriate function to use.

Comment: Hmm, you seem to be right.  It's been a while since I did UNIX programming, but I remember it being presented as a system call, obviously incorrectly.  In any case, the appropriate reference is the Stevens book, which notes this equivalence (iirc, as my man page doesn't)

Answer (score 4):

The child will run in the background since you used `fork`.  The child will keep running in parallel with the parent (if `exec` succeeded).  If you care about whether the child process succeeded or not (and your code should) you should eventually call `waitpid` to collect its exit status.   Otherwise you should call `fork` *twice* and have the intermediate process exit without `wait`ing for the child, so that `init` adopts the grandchild process.

As @mah said, the `&` is unnecessary.  But another change is needed to that line; `execl` is a variadic function, and function prototypes therefore don't take care of converting arguments to the correct type.   Therefore the final argument should be passed as the correct type - just change it to `(char*)NULL`.

You mention that your code didn't work.   While that could just be because of the spurious `&`, it may also be because of the first argument.   The `execl` function does not search `$PATH` for the named program, so unless `newproc` is actually in the current directory, this `execl()` invocation will return.   When `execl` returns, that always indicates that there is a problem.   The simplest way to solve this is to use `execlp()` instead of `execl()`.   The alternative approach is to specify an absolute path as the first argument.   You can even specify a relative path as the first argument, but this is rarely useful.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is not a command argument, its a flag that the shell uses to know to run the command in the background. In this case, you're performing the work of the shell... remove the `&`. Since you state you've called `fork()`, as long as you're only performing `execl()` in the child process after fork returns, you're already running in the background.