# How do I detect if a user types '&' after program and parameters when using dummy shell?

Tags: c, arrays, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a dummy shell and I want it to be able to be able to run whatever program the user enters in the background if the user types an '&' at the end.  However, I'm not sure how to check if the user types an '&' at the end.  I already tried: `printf("%c\n", args[ARRAY_SIZE-1])` but that doesn't seem to print anything.  I did in order to see if I can access the '&'.  How can I go about doing this?

The code I'm working with is below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1<<16

static void parseCmdArgs(char *buffer, char** cmdArgs, 
                size_t cmdArgsSize, size_t *nargs)
{
    char *bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]; 
    char **temp;
    char *buf;
    size_t n, p;

    cmdArgs[0] = buf = bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;  

    for(temp=bufCmdArgs; (*temp=strsep(&buf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*temp != '\0') && (++temp >= &bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]))
            break;
    }

    for (p=n=0; bufCmdArgs[n]!=NULL; n++){
        if(strlen(bufCmdArgs[n])>0)
            cmdArgs[p++]=bufCmdArgs[n];
    }

    *nargs=p;
    cmdArgs[p]=NULL;
}
  //int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *args[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int retStatus;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t pid;

    while(1){

        printf("$dummyshell ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        parseCmdArgs(buffer, args, ARRAY_SIZE, &nargs); 


        if (nargs==0)
            continue;

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "help"))
        {
            printf("cat                    cd (absolute path references only\n");
            printf("exit\n");
            printf("help                   history\n");
            printf("jobs                   kill\n");
            printf("ls                     more\n");
            printf("ps                     pwd\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit" ))
            exit(0);

        pid = fork();

        if (pid){      
            pid = wait(&retStatus);
        }

        else {
            if( execvp(args[0], args)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(127);
            }
        }

    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most shells will *consume* the `&` (which is normally taken to mean "run in background") and thus it is *not passed* to the program. To pass this to a program, the shell-specific interpretation must be disabled, e.g: `./program "&"`

Comment: If it's not passed to the program, how would I go about changing my code to have the option of running a program in the background?

Comment: Let the shell run the program in the background. The program normally doesn't need to do a thing. Now, if the requirement/task is "How to detect when a process is running in the background", then *ask that question* (as a different question). X is X, not Y.

Comment: @user2864740, are you saying my dummy shell is already capable of running a program in the background?  Cause it does not appear so.  Whenever I put an '&' at the end, the dummy shell runs the program in the foreground.  If it runs the program in the background, the dummyshell's prompt should appear immediately right?

Comment: No. Please see my answer. The dummy shell must do whatever shells do (or whatever it wants to do). I was suggesting that the `&` - as parsed/handled by the containing shell - is independent of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Most shells will *consume* the `&` token (which is normally taken to mean "run in background") and thus it is *not supplied as an argument* to the program.

To pass a "&" argument to the program, the shell-specific interpretation must be disabled, e.g.: `./dummyshell "programtorun" "&"` (two arguments) or `./dummyshell "programtorun &"` (one argument).

*Real* shells normally read from STDIN (or perhaps a terminal directly) or can be supplied a string of commands to execute, like: `sh -c "nohup program &"`.

Reading the input directly avoids the previous mentioned shell parsing and using quotes once again protects the `&` in the commands from being handled by the shell used to execute the (`sh`) command; note how the entire set of commands to run are passed as a *single* argument in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're suggesting.  I just want to know how to change my dummy shell so that it can run programs in the background when the user types '&' at the end.  I do not want to pass the '&' argument to the user inputted program.

Comment: @user2264035 **"How do I detect if a user types '&' after program and parameters when using dummy shell?"** To "change" your dummyshell, first you have to *get* the `&` into a string (see above), then you have to *parse* the appropriate argument or arguments (see above; such that it understands `&`) then you have to use functions like `daemon` (or emulate it with fork/fork/close/etc).

Comment: I was under the impression that I would have to detect if the user types '&' if I wanted the dummy shell to run the user's program in the background.  Is this not the case?

Comment: @user2264035 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972310/running-a-new-child-process-in-background-c-linux